# Using ampscript to get all records in a data extension between 2 dates

Tags: ampscript

Using Marketing Cloud:

I have a data extension with a date field.
On a cloudpage, using ampscript, i need to get all the records from that data extension where the date field is between/including 2 dates.

The LookupRows function seems to be the best available but i can only directly compare values to each other, it can't use a "between" statement.

What would be the best way to achieve this ? 
( Other than executing a LookupRows for each date separately )

Comment: You'll get a lot more eyes on your SFMC questions over at [salesforce.stackexchange.com](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com), specifically with the [marketing-cloud](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marketing-cloud) and [ampscript](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ampscript) tags.

Comment: It's better to do this ahead of time with a Query Activity -- otherwise you'll need to iterate through all of the rows and use a conditional to pick out rows from the range you want.

Comment: @AdamSpriggs, from what i've read i can't give parameters to a Query Activity. I would need to be able to give a start and end date to look for.